# ASP.NET Some service register after mediator

Tags: asp.net, mediator

We are working on service which collect data from AWS SQS then send batch to client. We are using mediator to publish notifications. The diagram of program looks like:
[image: Program diagram]

The problem is in first NotificationHandler from Mediatr.

```
private readonly EventCollectorHostedService _collector;

public CollectIncomingEventNotificationHandler(EventCollectorHostedService collector)
{
    _collector = collector;
}
```

Class EventCollectorHostedService is register after Mediator so is not visible during registering this NotificationHandler and additionally it  use Mediator to publish notification that batch is ready to send.
The error is that cannot construct CollectIncomingEventNotificationHandler because -> Unable to resolve service for type 'Api.Services.HostedServices.EventCollectorHostedService'.

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
services.AddHostedService<EventCollectorHostedService>();
```

The ugly solution is to declare some functionality in EventCollectorHostedService as static or instead of injecting EventCollectorHostedService, inject IServiceProvider.
But these solution don't look clean for me so do you have any other better solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone encountered with similar problem so finally i have a brilliant solution.
Background services have to be treat like separate microservices based on event driven architecture so we have to make  internal message broker mechanism.
The very simple solution which cover  my case is:

```
public class NotificationChannel : INotificationChannel
{
    public event EventHandler<IncomingEventNotificataionEventArgs> IncomingEventReceived;

    public void Publish<T>(T notification)
    {
        if(notification is IncomingEventNotification incomingEventNotification)
        {
            OnIncomingEventReceived(incomingEventNotification);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnIncomingEventReceived(IncomingEventNotification notification)
    {
        if(IncomingEventReceived != null)
        {
            var args = new IncomingEventNotificataionEventArgs(notification);
            IncomingEventReceived(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```